# NUnit test order shared among fixtures

Tags: c#, testing, nunit

I have a test fixture that has some cases in it (test1-test5).
Logically, the test cases should run one by one horizontally:

- all test1 cases among the different fixtures should run first
- all test2 cases among the different fixtures should run after
- ...

The cases should be batched together (due to another restriction).

I have tried to use the OrderAttribute but it seems like the order occurs in each fixture but not globally shared between them. Any ideas?

Here is the code sample:

```
[TestFixture, TestFixtureSource(nameof(TestFixture))]
public class TestCases
{
    [Test, Order(1)]
    public async Task Test1()
    {
        ...
    }

    [Test, Order(2)]
    public async Task Test2()
    {
        ...
    }

    [Test, Order(3)]
    public async Task Test3()
    {
        ...
    }

    [Test, Order(4)]
    public async Task Test4()
    {
        ...
    }

    [Test, Order(5)]
    public async Task Test5()
    {
        ...
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

That simply won't work. You appear to want a general ability to make tests dependent on one another, which has been discussed but never actually implemented in NUnit.

The fixture is the key organizational structure used in NUnit. If all your "Test1" cases need to run together, maybe they should be in the same fixture. Or maybe all your tests need to be in one fixture - although that sounds messy.

This sort of thing usually happens in organizations where some sort of rule is set up about how fixtures are organized and that rule doesn't pay attention to how NUnit uses fixtures.

I recognize this is not much of an answer for you, but since you have not actually said **why** you need to run your tests in this order, it's not possible to suggest an alternative approach. If you edit your question, I'll be glad to edit my answer. :-)

Comment: What I am trying to do is enter a record into a MQ and then there is a process with a latency that enters its data into a few sources of data in a specific order, thus I need to check each source separately in the right order...

Comment: Can't this be restructured so that the sequence of tests that have to be run in order are in one fixture?